# How to display content from one site on another using PHP?

Tags: php

I heard once that this could be done using Curl, but I don't want to display all contents from an external site on my site, but only the contents from a particular div. How can this be done?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [PHP Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to grab a page and easily select parts of it.

As easy as:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
$ret = $html->find('div[id=foo]');
```

Documentation [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

If what you want to do is grab the header of http://www.freeoh.net/, the following code will work. You need to place simple_html_dom.php and a file called page.txt (make sure the script has privileges to read and write to it) in the same folder as the following script. (I'm assuming you already have cURL enabled, as you mentioned it in your question.)

```
<?php

include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.freeoh.net/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.freeoh.net/");

$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
//write contents of $result to file
$File = "page.txt";
$fh = fopen($File, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $result);
fclose($fh);
//turn file into dom object
$page = file_get_html("page.txt");
$header = $page->find("div", 1);
echo $header;

?>
```

It's a little hacky because I used cURL to grab the page and then needed to store it somewhere so that PHP Simple HTML Dom parser would parse it properly, but it works.

Comment: This just breaks the page, for example run this:

<?php

   $html = file_get_html('http://www.freeoh.net/');
   $ret = $html->find('div[id=header]');

?>

Comment: Edited my answer.  If you want to grab the header from the site, the code is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl to get the html from the URL you want to, and then parse the results to "grab" this div you want.

Answer (score 0):

By scraping as what jorge said.
You still need to use Curl and regex.

Comment: Regex will be unreliable. A DOM parser will be much more reliable.