# Get specific content out of an URL read using CURL

Tags: php, curl

How can I get specific content out of a URL fed into CURL? I'm unsure as to how to begin doing this, and haven't been able to Google for it properly since I don't know exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: yes, sorry, what I want is a portion of the HTML result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already written an answer about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734136/how-to-display-content-from-one-site-on-another-using-php/2734152#2734152) for a question entitled "[How to display content from one site on another using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734136/how-to-display-content-from-one-site-on-another-using-php/2734152)"

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to use regexes to do a search for the local portion of the page that you want to scrape for content look up

http://php.net/preg_match

Comment: I suggest another post if you have trouble creating an exact regex to get the portion of the page you want...

Comment: -1: No, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no! **Never scrape HTML using regular expressions.** Use a parser like phpQuery or DOMDocument, but not regular expressions... NO... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: I didn't say he should use regular expressions to parse HTML. I said he should use a regex to find the *content* he was interested in. I challenge you to use any DOM in the world to narrow down a block of *content* to the few pieces of information you want...

Comment: You narrow it down to the container the information is in and then parse the text nodes. You do NOT use regex on an HTML document.

Comment: I'll take that as an "I'm sorry, go ahead and use a regex to find the specific content you are interested in." Noting, that the user *edit* only stated  after *end edit* my answer that it was an HTML document that curl was returning.

Comment: @Zak: gee, I don't know... Isn't most of the documents off the net in HTML format?